# While creating proxy service based on wsdl, by default its taking soap 1.1, so how can we convert or make it to use it as soap 1.2

Tags: osb, soap1.2

When i try to create an Proxy service in OSB based on WSDL, by default its considering soap version as 1.1 but my requirement is to use soap version 1.2, so can anyone help me on how to change the soap version to 1.2.

WSDl file doesn't contain any soap version details neither at binding level nor at port level.

Thanks,
Anil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a little your wsdl file and start using your soap 1.2 namespace. After that change, when you try create Proxy service from updated wsdl, you should achieve your goal.

Soap namespaces:

```
soap 1.1: xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
soap 1.2: xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
```

You can use it proper in your wsdl file.

If you can provide your wsdl i can help you change it correctly, if you still gonna be struggling with it.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply,

the namespaces for both soap 1.1 and soap 1.2 were already declared at wsdl:defination level.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wns="http://xxxx/qrcode/v1.1/" xmlns:tns="http://xxx/types/v0.1/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:cns="http://xxxxcommon/types/v0.1/" name="QrCode" targetNamespace="http://xxxx/qrcode/v1.1/">
    <wsdl:types>

Comment: <schema xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wns="http://xxxx/qrcode/v1.1/" xmlns:tns="http://xxxx/types/v0.1/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:cns="http://xxxxcommon/types/v0.1/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.0" targetNamespace="http://xxxx/qrcode/v1.1/">

Comment: <import namespace="http://xxxxcommon/types/v0.1/" schemaLocation="xsd/xxxcommon.xsd"/>  
  <import namespace="http://xxxx/types/v0.1/" schemaLocation="xsd/xxxtypes.xsd"/>
 </element>    
</schema>

Comment: Could you please let me know how can i add big file here..i have copy pasted start of wsdl file definition details.

Comment: I guess you can edit your main post, and could add whole wsdl

Comment: 1st solution
The easiest way (not cleanest) is change your namespace declaration from : xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" to
xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
and then create your proxy service

why that will work? Because i think in your wsdl file you are using only 'soap' namespace. 

2nd solution 
change all 'soap' namespaces in wsdl to soap12.

Keep asking if you still got problem

Answer (score 1):

issue resolved after adding extra service in the wsdl file, like below.

```
<wsdl:service name="Server">
        <!-- SOAP1.1 Service -->
        <wsdl:port name="ServerSoap" binding="tns:ServerSoap">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Server" />
    </wsdl:port>

        <!-- SOAP1.2 Service -->
    <wsdl:port name="ServerSoap12" binding="tns:ServerSoap12">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/Server" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Thanks,
Anil.